# Webservices Error related to XML Schema

Tags: .net, web-services, xml-serialization

I am trying to make a simple web service with the following XML schema as response to some operation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="TResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="STATUS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="DESCRIPTION" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="Result" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="List" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Attributes" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="AttrName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="AttrValue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

The above schema was created using XSD.exe tool of VS 2005 using the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TResponse>
      <STATUS>string</STATUS>
      <DESCRIPTION>string</DESCRIPTION>
      <Result>      
        <List>         
            <Attributes>
        <AttrName>Test1</AttrName>
            <AttrValue>TestV1</AttrValue>
        </Attributes>     
        </List>
      </Result>
    </TResponse>
```

Now with the help of XSD.exe tool I have generated the C# classes for this XML schema and used that class as message in my webservice application. Everything is fine here until I try to make a simple call from client created using .net framework.

The error I received is

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'TResponseResultListAttributes[][]' to 'TResponseResultListAttributes[]'

  at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
  at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
  at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Evidence evidence)
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerType..ctor(Type type, WebServiceProtocols protocolsSupported)
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I found one article which seems to be talking something related to my error but that is not helping me.

Any insight please.

Comment: The link to article is http://www.kerrywong.com/2006/11/04/xml-serialization-surprise-in-vs-2005/

Comment: Exactly what the error message tells you. You probably created the schema class wrong, which is not surprising using inference to create a schema. It would be better to roll it by hand.

Comment: Thanks leppie but i tried to do it without success.

Comment: I have found one article on msdn which turns out to be life saver for me - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/e33305c3-b5f6-4922-8a3f-df202088d25a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article solve the problem I faced.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/e33305c3-b5f6-4922-8a3f-df202088d25a